# Represent double value as NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What is the correct way of represent double value as NSString ? 
In my code, it is calculating or rather doing some kind of rounding..I am not sure. Below is my code;

```
X = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [abc doubleValue] - [xyz doubleValue]];
```

I am getting
abc is 69206000000, xyz is 31687000000, X is 58720256

Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `%f` format modifier to display a double value - the `%d` in your code refers to an integer value. (See [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for more info.)

Comment: `%f` displays a float. The correct answer is `%lf` for long float (double).

Comment: Apple's [NSString format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/articles/formatSpecifiers.html) say that `%f` is a "64-bit floating-point number (`double`)." What's more, the `l` argument (under Table 2 for length modifiers) is documented to apply only to `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X`.

Comment: And even further, Table 3 explicitly says: "`%f` works for floats and doubles when formatting..."

Answer (score 8):

Use `%lf` for double value

```
X = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", [abc doubleValue] - [xyz doubleValue]];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

%d is for integers so you'll get some funky output passing in a double or float. Try this instead:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [abc doubleValue] - [xyz doubleValue]];
```

Answer (score 1):

%d means integer. Use %f. Read up on format specifiers.